# Why past simple in this sentence of Jane Austen's book "Persuasion"?

Tags: past-tense

I found this sentence in Persuasion by Jane Austen:

> Till he came and had examined the child, their apprehensions **were** the worst for being vague; they suspected great injury, but knew not where; but now the collar-bone was soon replaced..

I don't understand why it is not "**had been the worst**" because their apprehensions were vague before the child had been examined.They came and had these apprehensions then after the child had been examined they were gone. They knew exactly what the child suffered from.

Could it mean that they still have apprehensions after the child examination? , I don't think so .

May be as the sequence of time is crystal clear we can use past simple ? There is no possible  confusion especially because there is only one event the examination so  past simple can do it

I know the structure of the sentence is a bit special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constituents of the sentence can be reordered so:

> Their apprehensions were the worst for being vague till he came and had examined the child.

Notice **had examined**.  The examination takes place *after* his arrival, and his arrival takes place *after* their apprehensions had begun. And yet the past perfect is used of the more *recent* event. The past perfect is used there to indicate the examination had been *completed*, as examination is a process.

There is no grammatical requirement to put **were** in the past perfect and say **had been**, and indeed, for Austen to have done so would have made her sentence clunky:

> Their apprehensions <strike>were</strike> **had been** the worst for being vague till he came and had examined the child.

or in the original order:

> Till he came and had examined the child, their apprehensions <strike>were</strike> **had been** the worst for being vague; ...

We would have two verbs in the past perfect (had been, had examined) and **been** and **being** would be jostling.

They would have continued to worry during the examination. Their fears were the worst because they didn't know the extent of the injury, but once the examination had been completed they then knew the extent of the injury, and the worst aspect of their worry was alleviated:

> [T]hey suspected great injury, but knew not where; but now the collar-bone was soon replaced.

Comment: So with were the worry disappears at the beginning of the examination with had been at the end of examination?

Comment: @YvesLefol   The meaning is not *entailed* by the choice of tense.  The past perfect **had examined** simply indicates the examination had been completed.  But *from context* (the narrative details) we understand that their worry was alleviated *once they knew the extent of the injury*, and that is only after the examination was completed, and presumably the physician had informed them of the findings.